# How to make B fixed with respect to A

Tags: css

B scrolls with the content of A. I want it stay fixed, i.e. not scroll with the content of A. How can I do that?"A" is also a block and "B" is inside "A".

[image: Description of positioning problem]

Comment: I have tried "position:fixed" already but then B seems to move out of "A" and aligns itself to rightmost of the browser window

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/frXKp/2/ .
I want block "B" to stay inside "A",not outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `position:fixed;` CSS tag.

```
div#b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position:fixed` rather than `position:absolute`